# does nextjs prerenders html which is displayed conditionally and is not presented initially?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

does nextjs prerenders html on a page which is diplayed only when some button in clicked, for example? Or when we have tabs, does it renders content of ones which are not displayed yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not just for Next.js but React, generally it will depend on how you are conditionally showing/hiding the component, especially if it is hidden by css or javascript. Here is an example:

```js
// 1. returning an empty fragment or component
const Component1 = ({ isVisible }) => {
  if (!isVisible) return <></>;
  return (
    <div>Hello World</div>
  )
}

// 2. changing the display property
const Component2 = ({ isVisible }) => {
  const display = isVisible ? "flex" : "hidden";
  return (
    <div style={{ display }}>Hello World</div>
  )
}
```

1. In the first example a empty fragment is rendered when the `isVisible` property is set to `false`. An empty fragment does not produce any html.
2. In the second example we just change the css `display` property based on the prop, while not visible the generated html will still be included in your html.